# Track Changes in any Java Object with a Copy

Tags: java, object, serialization, garbage-collection

I am working on a serialization function in Java which should ideally take any class that implements an interface (similar to Serializable).  As part of that, I would like to track changes to the objects which implement the serialization interface automatically.  In order to do this, I am trying to have a clone of the last-written object- copied upon reading in from persistence and in memory only as long as the altered version.  However, I am having trouble coming up with a proper way to have a reference between the two (original and altered) objects that does not eat up large amounts of memory.  Thus far, I have considered a few ways to do this, all with problems:

1. Add a member to the altered object class/superclass which references the original version clone so that, each time the altered object is written, the writer can access the original and calculate the difference.  However, this would require using inheritance to properly accomplish, which is bad form for this, particularly considering that Java only allows one superclass (what happens when we want to perform serialization on an object that extends something else?  Also, it does not necessarily make semantic sense that the object in question "is a" something that allows it to be serialized).  This cannot be accomplished with the interface (interfaces, of course, do not allow for the declaration of variables).
2. Have some sort of a linking data structure- perhaps a static map somewhere.  This fails because the linking structure will always have a reference to the altered object, which prevents it from being deallocated in garbage collection even when the operational parts of code have long since dereferenced the object.  Maybe there is some way to make a reference that is not looked at by the garbage collector- perhaps with Java hashing?
3. Add the cloned original to the altered copy as a dynamic member (perhaps private/hidden) at runtime somehow, maybe with reflection.  This seems like incredibly bad form, but would add a reference only from the altered version to the original clone which means that there would be no GC issues (the original clone does not have any references other than from the altered version) assuming that the GC will detect the reference from the altered to the original.

Are there any other obvious things I am missing here?  Any ways to make the solutions above work?

Answer (score 1):

Since there does not seem to be a better way, I am going to write some code which automatically extends the class of the object to be serialized. The new subclass will have the clone as a member but will be treated as the superclass everywhere except the serialization code. The only conflicts I see from this arise from Object.getClassName() and it's related functionality (instanceof). Perhaps I can figure out a way to overwrite the getClassName method. I wish there was an easier way to get this type of transparency though.